# Voice Detection in Android Application

Tags: android, voice-detection

## Description

---

My application record sound from phone microphone. I am using android standard classes (`android.media.AudioRecord`) to do that. Application have 2 buttons "**Start**" and "**Stop**" when I press **start** button application start record and when I press **stop** application stops recording and give me back buffer, with voice data in .wav format. All work fine.

## Problem

---

I want to change my application in this way, when application start work it begin to analyze sound coming from microphone, if user keep silent application continue to analyze income sound from microphone, if user start to talk application begin to **Record** sound coming from microphone and then user finish talking application stops recording and give me back same buffer, with voice data in .wav format.

## Question

---

1. How I can detect that user **start to talk**
2. How I can detect that user **stop to talk**

Comment: I think you will have to do most of the sound work on your own - Android does provide some limited functions for accessing the mic and recording, but nothing that does heavy computation or speech to text.

Comment: @sqrfv thanks for comment, +1 Any other suggestion ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just add this code to your application and you will detect when user start to speak and when he stops.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Get the minimum buffer size required for the successful creation of an AudioRecord object. 
    int bufferSizeInBytes = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize( RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
                                                          RECORDER_CHANNELS,
                                                          RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING
                                                         ); 
    // Initialize Audio Recorder.
    AudioRecord audioRecorder = new AudioRecord( MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                                                 RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
                                                 RECORDER_CHANNELS,
                                                 RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING,
                                                 bufferSizeInBytes
                                                );
    // Start Recording.
    audioRecorder.startRecording();

    int numberOfReadBytes   = 0; 
    byte audioBuffer[]      = new  byte[bufferSizeInBytes];
    boolean recording       = false;
    float tempFloatBuffer[] = new float[3];
    int tempIndex           = 0;
    int totalReadBytes      = 0;
    byte totalByteBuffer[]  = new byte[60 * 44100 * 2];


    // While data come from microphone. 
    while( true )
    {
        float totalAbsValue = 0.0f;
        short sample        = 0; 

        numberOfReadBytes = audioRecorder.read( audioBuffer, 0, bufferSizeInBytes );

        // Analyze Sound.
        for( int i=0; i<bufferSizeInBytes; i+=2 ) 
        {
            sample = (short)( (audioBuffer[i]) | audioBuffer[i + 1] << 8 );
            totalAbsValue += Math.abs( sample ) / (numberOfReadBytes/2);
        }

        // Analyze temp buffer.
        tempFloatBuffer[tempIndex%3] = totalAbsValue;
        float temp                   = 0.0f;
        for( int i=0; i<3; ++i )
            temp += tempFloatBuffer[i];

        if( (temp >=0 && temp <= 350) && recording == false )
        {
            Log.i("TAG", "1");
            tempIndex++;
            continue;
        }

        if( temp > 350 && recording == false )
        {
            Log.i("TAG", "2");
            recording = true;
        }

        if( (temp >= 0 && temp <= 350) && recording == true )
        {
            Log.i("TAG", "Save audio to file.");

            // Save audio to file.
            String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
            File file = new File(filepath,"AudioRecorder");
            if( !file.exists() )
                file.mkdirs();

            String fn = file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".wav";

            long totalAudioLen  = 0;
            long totalDataLen   = totalAudioLen + 36;
            long longSampleRate = RECORDER_SAMPLERATE;
            int channels        = 1;
            long byteRate       = RECORDER_BPP * RECORDER_SAMPLERATE * channels/8;
            totalAudioLen       = totalReadBytes;
            totalDataLen        = totalAudioLen + 36;
            byte finalBuffer[]  = new byte[totalReadBytes + 44];

            finalBuffer[0] = 'R';  // RIFF/WAVE header
            finalBuffer[1] = 'I';
            finalBuffer[2] = 'F';
            finalBuffer[3] = 'F';
            finalBuffer[4] = (byte) (totalDataLen & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[5] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 8) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[6] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 16) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[7] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 24) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[8] = 'W';
            finalBuffer[9] = 'A';
            finalBuffer[10] = 'V';
            finalBuffer[11] = 'E';
            finalBuffer[12] = 'f';  // 'fmt ' chunk
            finalBuffer[13] = 'm';
            finalBuffer[14] = 't';
            finalBuffer[15] = ' ';
            finalBuffer[16] = 16;  // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
            finalBuffer[17] = 0;
            finalBuffer[18] = 0;
            finalBuffer[19] = 0;
            finalBuffer[20] = 1;  // format = 1
            finalBuffer[21] = 0;
            finalBuffer[22] = (byte) channels;
            finalBuffer[23] = 0;
            finalBuffer[24] = (byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[25] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[26] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[27] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[28] = (byte) (byteRate & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[29] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[30] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[31] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[32] = (byte) (2 * 16 / 8);  // block align
            finalBuffer[33] = 0;
            finalBuffer[34] = RECORDER_BPP;  // bits per sample
            finalBuffer[35] = 0;
            finalBuffer[36] = 'd';
            finalBuffer[37] = 'a';
            finalBuffer[38] = 't';
            finalBuffer[39] = 'a';
            finalBuffer[40] = (byte) (totalAudioLen & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[41] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 8) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[42] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 16) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[43] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 24) & 0xff);

            for( int i=0; i<totalReadBytes; ++i )
                finalBuffer[44+i] = totalByteBuffer[i];

            FileOutputStream out;
            try {
                out = new FileOutputStream(fn);
                 try {
                        out.write(finalBuffer);
                        out.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            //*/
            tempIndex++;
            break;
        }

        // -> Recording sound here.
        Log.i( "TAG", "Recording Sound." );
        for( int i=0; i<numberOfReadBytes; i++ )
            totalByteBuffer[totalReadBytes + i] = audioBuffer[i];
        totalReadBytes += numberOfReadBytes;
        //*/

        tempIndex++;

    }
}
```

Check this [link](http://vitobrothersoft.com/2011/11/04/voice-detection-for-android/).

Comment: I tried this code but it is not working for me i am getting the exception as follows

Please help me to come out from this problem

Comment: 04-06 15:03:01.729: E/AndroidRuntime(16174): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 0Hz is not a supported sample rate.
04-06 15:03:01.729: E/AndroidRuntime(16174):  at android.media.AudioRecord.audioParamCheck(AudioRecord.java:265)
04-06 15:03:01.729: E/AndroidRuntime(16174):  at android.media.AudioRecord.<init>(AudioRecord.java:223)
04-06 15:03:01.729: E/AndroidRuntime(16174):  at com.test.recording.RecordingActivity.onCreate(RecordingActivity.java:32)

04-06 15:03:01.729: E/AndroidRuntime(16174):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)

Comment: private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE 
which value should i give it here???

Comment: Please help me as soon as possible

Comment: @Dipali 
`private static final int RECORDER_BPP = 16;`
`private static int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 8000;`
`private static int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;`
    private static int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

Comment: @ViToBrothers can you explain or point me somewhere to understand how the audio analyzing is done? Specifically the code following the `// Analyze Sound.` and `// Analyze temp buffer.` comments.

Comment: Can i use this example to start an activity when a voice is detected?

Comment: But the voice stored in .wav file is unable to read. Can you help me with that?

Comment: i created a new project and pasted the above exactly in that project but the log say "Recording Sound" and never stops and then crashes with not responding error; could you tell me the solution to this

Comment: Site can't be reached

Comment: i get an error "startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord"

Comment: This just hangs the phone.

Comment: @Kumararaja If you are running on Android 6 or above you have to write the runtime permission code for Record Audio and write storage

Comment: @VijayE Its because the code is executing on main thread and while loop keeps on running

Answer (score 2):

it is better to used private static final int **RECORDER_SAMPLERAT=8000**;
it works for me.I think it will help for you

Answer (score 1):

when i replaced `totalAbsValue += Math.abs( sample ) / (numberOfReadBytes/2) by totalAbsValue += (float)Math.abs( sample ) / ((float)numberOfReadBytes/(float)2)` then it work fine.