# How to draw waveform of Android's audio recording?

Tags: android

I would like to show a waveform during the audio recording.
Some example please?

Thank you.

Comment: hi,did you found solution for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look at the answer here : [Voice Detection in Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955041/voice-detection-in-android-application) to find out how to record into a byte[]. Then all you have to do is draw a graph of each value in the byte[] as a function of time.

Comment: Use the link I provided above to get your audio into a byte[] then post what you have.