# How to navigate pages using voice command in android

Tags: android, voice-recognition

How to develop a voice recognition application in offline mode in android.

i used [this](http://swathiep.blogspot.com/2011/02/offline-speech-recognition-with.html) and [this](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android) link

but now i need to improve my application to reduce the noises. That is mean to detect human voice.
So i used

[Voice Detection in Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955041/voice-detection-in-android-application)

but i got errors
e.g

> E/AndroidRuntime(16174): Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 0Hz is not a supported sample
>   rate. 04-06 15:03:01.729: E/AndroidRuntime(16174)

so i kindly request to help me.If there is other way please let me know

thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
0Hz is not a supported sample rate
```

Suggests that you didn't supply a valid sample rate, check that part of the code again and see if you forgot it

Comment: what you mean by valid sample rate i didn't get it.Please can you explain it more

Comment: As you didn't supply any source code I could only guess what's missing by looking at your error message. If no valid sample rate is supported by your code, you will have to look at your source code to find the problem