# why the UI does not show till the while loop breaks?

Tags: android, pitch-detection, voice-detection

this code is answered in [Voice Detection in Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955041/voice-detection-in-android-application).
It works fine but there is issue that the content of the page does not load until and unless the any voice has been detected and this snippet also makes the app crash few a times

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Get the minimum buffer size required for the successful creation of an AudioRecord object. 
    int bufferSizeInBytes = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize( RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
                                                          RECORDER_CHANNELS,
                                                          RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING
                                                         ); 
    // Initialize Audio Recorder.
    AudioRecord audioRecorder = new AudioRecord( MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                                                 RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
                                                 RECORDER_CHANNELS,
                                                 RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING,
                                                 bufferSizeInBytes
                                                );
    // Start Recording.
    audioRecorder.startRecording();

    int numberOfReadBytes   = 0; 
    byte audioBuffer[]      = new  byte[bufferSizeInBytes];
    boolean recording       = false;
    float tempFloatBuffer[] = new float[3];
    int tempIndex           = 0;
    int totalReadBytes      = 0;
    byte totalByteBuffer[]  = new byte[60 * 44100 * 2];


    // While data come from microphone. 
    while( true )
    {
        float totalAbsValue = 0.0f;
        short sample        = 0; 

        numberOfReadBytes = audioRecorder.read( audioBuffer, 0, bufferSizeInBytes );

        // Analyze Sound.
        for( int i=0; i<bufferSizeInBytes; i+=2 ) 
        {
            sample = (short)( (audioBuffer[i]) | audioBuffer[i + 1] << 8 );
            totalAbsValue += Math.abs( sample ) / (numberOfReadBytes/2);
        }

        // Analyze temp buffer.
        tempFloatBuffer[tempIndex%3] = totalAbsValue;
        float temp                   = 0.0f;
        for( int i=0; i<3; ++i )
            temp += tempFloatBuffer[i];

        if( (temp >=0 && temp <= 350) && recording == false )
        {
            Log.i("TAG", "1");
            tempIndex++;
            continue;
        }

        if( temp > 350 && recording == false )
        {
            Log.i("TAG", "2");
            recording = true;
        }

        if( (temp >= 0 && temp <= 350) && recording == true )
        {
            Log.i("TAG", "Save audio to file.");

            // Save audio to file.
            String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
            File file = new File(filepath,"AudioRecorder");
            if( !file.exists() )
                file.mkdirs();

            String fn = file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".wav";

            long totalAudioLen  = 0;
            long totalDataLen   = totalAudioLen + 36;
            long longSampleRate = RECORDER_SAMPLERATE;
            int channels        = 1;
            long byteRate       = RECORDER_BPP * RECORDER_SAMPLERATE * channels/8;
            totalAudioLen       = totalReadBytes;
            totalDataLen        = totalAudioLen + 36;
            byte finalBuffer[]  = new byte[totalReadBytes + 44];

            finalBuffer[0] = 'R';  // RIFF/WAVE header
            finalBuffer[1] = 'I';
            finalBuffer[2] = 'F';
            finalBuffer[3] = 'F';
            finalBuffer[4] = (byte) (totalDataLen & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[5] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 8) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[6] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 16) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[7] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 24) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[8] = 'W';
            finalBuffer[9] = 'A';
            finalBuffer[10] = 'V';
            finalBuffer[11] = 'E';
            finalBuffer[12] = 'f';  // 'fmt ' chunk
            finalBuffer[13] = 'm';
            finalBuffer[14] = 't';
            finalBuffer[15] = ' ';
            finalBuffer[16] = 16;  // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
            finalBuffer[17] = 0;
            finalBuffer[18] = 0;
            finalBuffer[19] = 0;
            finalBuffer[20] = 1;  // format = 1
            finalBuffer[21] = 0;
            finalBuffer[22] = (byte) channels;
            finalBuffer[23] = 0;
            finalBuffer[24] = (byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[25] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[26] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[27] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[28] = (byte) (byteRate & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[29] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[30] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[31] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[32] = (byte) (2 * 16 / 8);  // block align
            finalBuffer[33] = 0;
            finalBuffer[34] = RECORDER_BPP;  // bits per sample
            finalBuffer[35] = 0;
            finalBuffer[36] = 'd';
            finalBuffer[37] = 'a';
            finalBuffer[38] = 't';
            finalBuffer[39] = 'a';
            finalBuffer[40] = (byte) (totalAudioLen & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[41] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 8) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[42] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 16) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[43] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 24) & 0xff);

            for( int i=0; i<totalReadBytes; ++i )
                finalBuffer[44+i] = totalByteBuffer[i];

            FileOutputStream out;
            try {
                out = new FileOutputStream(fn);
                 try {
                        out.write(finalBuffer);
                        out.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            //*/
            tempIndex++;
            break;
        }

        // -> Recording sound here.
        Log.i( "TAG", "Recording Sound." );
        for( int i=0; i<numberOfReadBytes; i++ )
            totalByteBuffer[totalReadBytes + i] = audioBuffer[i];
        totalReadBytes += numberOfReadBytes;
        //*/

        tempIndex++;

    }
}
```